# Shift,Ctrl,Win Intercepting my autoclicking hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having a problem with a script my friend suggested me, it is working but whenever I press/hold Alt,Shift,Ctrl or windows my mouse's left button stops working. I made few researches and it appears than modifying `LButton` to `LButton` will fire those hotkeys and simply keeps the button working constantly (or as I understand) but it didn't work for me.

```
Ins::Suspend

*LButton::
  Loop {
    SetMouseDelay 30
    Click
    If (GetKeyState("LButton","P­")=0)
      Break

  }
  Return
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To stop the script from triggering itself, prefix your shortcut with `$`. Just to be extra safe, use `#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2` to prevent an accidental fork bomb.

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2

*Ins::Suspend

$*LButton::
loop
{
    SetMouseDelay 30
    If (GetKeyState("LButton","P­")=0)
      Break
    click
}
Return
```